# What is the point of this postgresql.service file?

Tags: systemd

This "services" appears to run /bin/true, but why?  There is another postgresql@.service file as well, but why does this one exist at all?  Yes, this is the entire file.

```
# systemd service for managing all PostgreSQL clusters on the system. This
# service is actually a systemd target, but we are using a service since
# targets cannot be reloaded.

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL RDBMS

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/true
ExecReload=/bin/true
RemainAfterExit=on

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a dummy service, a trigger that starts the actual PostgreSQL through *service dependencies*. The `/bin/true` just makes it to look like it has started successfully, without actually doing anything.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how this starts all of the instances on a machine?  Something I'm just missing here.  The `/bin/true` now makes sense, but just don't see how it launches all of the instances......

Answer (score 1):

The comments at the top are clear and explain the use. Each cluster has its own unit file postgresql@version-cluster and they are all "PartOf=postgresql.service". Thus this unit allows one to start up all clusters with `systemctl start postgresql` and other services to depend on all clusters being in a particular state (e.g., started).